# How to describe imbedding in simple terms?

Tags: general-topology

How to describe a topological imbedding in simple layman terms? Can we think of surface patches to be a form of an imbedding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An embedding is incorporating something as a part of the whole.
Yes, a patch of a surface is a part of it.